# Find minimum value of $|z+1+i|+|z-1-i|+|z-2|+|z-3|$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$  Find minimum value of $|z+1+i|+|z-1-i|+|z-2|+|z-3|$

All that i know is $$|z_1+z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$$ and i am not sure which two complex numbers i combine and use the above inequality. any geometrical approach?

Comment: @DougM aren't you forgetting couple of $y^2$ terms?. Also one of the $(x-1)^2$ should be $(x+1)^2$.

Comment: The value of $|z-2|$ for example is the distance between $z$ and the point $2$. So minimizing this value is about finding the point of minimum distance between these 4 points.

Comment: @DougM Why can we minimise that instead of the square roots?

Answer (score 5):

My previous answer turned out to be wrong as I misread the input.

Introducing the points as $A = (1,1)$, $B=(-1,-1)$, $C = (2,0)$ and $D = (3,0),$ we are supposed to find the minimum value of $$f(P) = PA+PB+PC+PD.$$
This is known as the [Fermat-Torricelli problem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fermat-Torricelli_problem) in general and its unique solution is called the [Geometric Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). In general, there is no closed form solution to this, but in the case of $4$ points it is known to be solvable.

To be explicit, the point that minimizes $f(P)$ is the intersection of two diagonals formed by $A,B,C,D$, *if they formed a convex quadrilateral.*

But our points form a non-convex quadrilateral with $C$ being inside the triangle formed by $A,B,D$. In this case, it is known that $f(P)$ attains its minimum at $P=C$, the point that is strictly inside the convex hull of $A,B,C,D.$

You can find a proof of the above in [this](http://research.vub.ac.be/sites/default/files/uploads/BUTO/Working-Papers/mosi_working_paper_16_-_plastria_f._2005_4-point_fermat_location_problems_revisited._new_proofs_and_extensions_of_old_results.pdf) paper.

Comment: Check the points again. $B$ should be $(-1,-1)$.

Comment: It is not just one number typed wrong, but the whole argument relies on the wrong number and now it fails after the correction.

Comment: yes, i see that just now. let me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The following contour plot suggests that the minimum is taken at $z_*:=2$. The minimum value would then be 
$$f(2)=1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{10}\doteq5.57649\ .$$

[image]

In order to **prove** that $z_*=2$ indeed gives the minimum we argue as follows: The function $f$ (considered as function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x+iy)$) is a sum of four convex functions, hence convex, and thus can have at most one isolated local minimum, which is then the global minimum. It is therefore sufficient to prove that $z_*$ is an isolated local minimum of $f$.

Consider the function
$$g(x,y):=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-3)^2+y^2}\ ,$$
which is $f$ with the term $|z-2|$ removed. Compute
$$a:=g_x(2,0)=-1+{1\over\sqrt{2}}+{3\over\sqrt{10}},\qquad b:=g_y(2,0)={1\over\sqrt{10}}-{1\over\sqrt{2}}\ .$$
It follows that
$$\bigl|\nabla g(2,0)\bigr|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\doteq0.763444<1\ .\tag{1}$$
Now at $z_*=2$ the directional derivative of $z\mapsto |z-2|$ is $\ +1$ in *all* directions. Together with $(1)$ we may therefore conclude that $f(z)=g(z)+|z-2|$ takes an isolated local minimum at $z_*$.